# cmake execute_process for python throws 'permission denied' error

Tags: python, cmake

I'm trying to build a C++ project on macOS using cmake. The project is a little complex but for the most part it seems to be compiling until it gets to a cmake file called `FindPythonLibsNew.cmake`. The call  `execute_process` is returning a 'Permission Denied' on the following call

(To see the entire FindPythonLibsNew.cmake, please visit [this link](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/blob/master/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake). It's the exact same file we have in our project

```
execute_process(COMMAND "${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}" "-c"
    "from distutils import sysconfig as s;import sys;import struct;
print('.'.join(str(v) for v in sys.version_info));
print(sys.prefix);
print(s.get_python_inc(plat_specific=True));
print(s.get_python_lib(plat_specific=True));
print(s.get_config_var('SO'));
print(hasattr(sys, 'gettotalrefcount')+0);
print(struct.calcsize('@P'));
print(s.get_config_var('LDVERSION') or s.get_config_var('VERSION'));
print(s.get_config_var('LIBDIR') or '');
print(s.get_config_var('MULTIARCH') or '');
"
    RESULT_VARIABLE _PYTHON_SUCCESS
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE _PYTHON_VALUES
    ERROR_VARIABLE _PYTHON_ERROR_VALUE)
```

The following is the output

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4 (Required is at least version "3") 
CMake Error at /Users/Developer/Development/cppProject/cmake/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:96 (message):
  Python config failure:

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake/pybind11/pybind11Tools.cmake:16 (find_package)
  /usr/local/share/cmake/pybind11/pybind11Config.cmake:100 (include)
  /Users/Developer/Development/cppProject/python_test/CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)
```

The `${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}` path is set to `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4`

If I try running the `print` statements through python3 they execute as expected, so the problem has to lie in how the cmake is trying to execute the python command. Unfortunately, I don't know enough cmake to fully understand how or where it's executing from.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to **reduce** `execute_process` call to the **minimal** form: If the error comes because of the first `import` statement, leave only that statement in the code which you show us. If the error comes only with specific `print` statement, remove all other prints from the code.

Comment: Executable named `3.7.4` looks wrong.

Comment: @arrowd Well, that's the path the the executable, should it be to something more specific?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I did try that; most basic was to just print out some string and see if it got a response, but it throw a permission error.

Comment: So `execute_process` throws an error with **any** `print` statement inside the python code? What if you just pass `print('Hello, world');` as a `-c` argument? Have you checked (outside of CMake) that `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4` is a correct python executable or a link to it? What is printed by `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4 --version`?

Comment: You both were correct. The path was wrong, which I'm not sure where it is being pulled from, to be honest. I got the python3 path directly and added it and now it's compiling successfully. Thank you for your  help.

Comment: `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` is taken from `find_package(PythonInterp)` in your `FindPythonLibsNew.cmake`. But normally this script reports a valid path.

Comment: I'm not sure what the deal is and why it wasn't picking it up correctly. I know a few others have had issues with Python paths too, but the project itself is in need of some clean up. Either way, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `FindPythonLibsNew.cmake` was pulling in the wrong path for the `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE`. I corrected this by adding `-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/bin/python3` to the cmake command. I'm sure there are better, more cleaner ways to fix this, but for the moment this will work for me.